# (Simple?) SQL Query: Display all customer information for customers with 2+ orders

Tags: sql

I'm doing practice exam material for a distance education course. I have the following three relations (simplified here):

```
salesperson(emp#, name, salary)
order(order#, cust#, emp#, total)
customer(cust#, name, city)
```

I'm stuck on a pair of SQL queries.

1. Display all customer info for customers with at least 1 order.

```
SELECT * FROM customer
  INNER JOIN order ON order.cust# = customer.cust#
  GROUP BY cust#;
```

2. Display all customer info for customers with at least 2 orders.

```
SELECT cust#, name, city, industry-type FROM customer
  INNER JOIN order ON order.cust# = customer.cust#
  GROUP BY cust#
  HAVING COUNT(cust#) > 2;
```

I realize these are misguided attempts resulting from a poor understanding of SQL, but I've spent a ton of time on W3School's SQL Query example tool (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_where) without getting anywhere, and I finally need some "real" help.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `subquery` to get `count` by `cust#` then do `inner join` to make it.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (
    SELECT cust# , COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM order 
    GROUP BY cust#
) o INNER JOIN customer c ON c.cust# = o.cust#
WHERE o.cnt > 2
```

Comment: I tried something very similar to this before, with something like: SELECT * FROM customers where cust# = (... select cust# which appears at least twice in orders ...). But your logic makes more sense: Work inside-out. Select cust# from order and group them up, then join that grouped-up table to all our customer data. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can change table names according to your DB. Following queries you can directly run in W3Schools

1. Display all customer info for customers with at least 1 order.

   SELECT * FROM customers as cust JOIN orders as o ON o.customerid =
   cust.customerid GROUP BY o.customerid;
2. Display all customer info for customers with at least 2 orders.

   SELECT * FROM customers as cust JOIN orders as O ON O.CustomerID = cust.CustomerID GROUP BY cust.CustomerID HAVING COUNT(cust.CustomerID) > 2;